# Tradução customizada do Humanize Django 2.2.x

Tags: python, django-2.2

Percebi que a versão `2.2.7` do Django veio com a tradução do humanize errada. Estou tendo um problema onde o meu naturaltime está retornando:

`6mesesatrás` e o correeto seria `6 meses atrás`.

Verificando a tradução do **humanize**, vi que o `django.po` está incorreto. Tentei seguir os steps para recriar as mensagens do django.po mas estou tendo dificuldades.

1) Primeiro criei a pasta `locale_extra/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/` na raiz do projeto.

2) Dentro desse diretório criei o arquivo: `django.po`

3) Adicionei o [django.po oficial do humanize](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/locale/pt_BR/LC_MESSAGES/django.po) porem com a tradução corrigida.

4) Adicionei o path no `settings.py` mencionando o `locale` padrão e o `locale_extra`:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    # default
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject', 'locale'),
    # custom
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myproject', 'locale_extra'),
)
```

5) Rodei o comando `compilemessages` e depois `makemessages`.

Resultado: nada aconteceu. O erro persiste. Provavelmente estou fazendo algo errado. Onde estou errando e como poderia corrigir a tradução do **humanize**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu estava rodando o comando da forma errada e percebi que a pasta `locale_extra` precisava estar dentro do `myproject/project` (onde fica o **settings.py**).

O comando correto é:

```
python manage.py makemessages -l pt_BR
python manage.py compilemessages -l pt_BR
```

> Obs.: Dessa forma ele vai gerar o `django.mo` e a tradução vai funcionar
>   corretamente. [Tentei fazer um pull request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/12170) no projeto do Django mas
>   pelo que entendi a [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/) que faz a tradução e faz 8 meses que
>   eles não traduzem de forma correta o **humanize**.